# how to remove pre-registration campaign on play store?

Tags: google-play, google-play-services, google-play-developer-api

I have published app on play store, I don't know why the app is showing Pre-Registration, I want to give direct download option to my users. Helping hands will be highly appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The [instructions for pre-registration are here](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9084187). But I'm not sure how this would have happened to you by accident.

To remove it and publish, see the section "Launch your app or game from pre-registration"

> - Sign in to your Play Console.
> - Select an app or game that you made available for pre-registration..
> - Click Store presence > Pricing & distribution.
> - In the “Countries” section, click Manage countries.
> - Next to the countries where you want to launch your app or game, select Available.
> - Select Submit update.
>
>   - Important: To make your app available on Google Play in the countries you select, make sure to publish your app or game on the Production track. You can publish on the Production track by selecting your app, and then selecting Release Management > App Releases.
>   - After it’s published to the Production track, your app or game will become available in any country set to “Available” on its Pricing & Distribution page.

Comment: Thanks a lot, @Nick Fortescue it's worked for me, actually I haven't select any country at the time of distribution, so that may be the reason.

Comment: Thanks! I "released" my app three days ago and it still says "coming soon". I thought it was just my user. Google's documentation on this is super lacking!

Comment: Thanks, but I'm getting `You should either add a new APK or deactivate an existing APK to create a new release.`. Why can't I just roll out by original APK to production??

Comment: This took forever to find!

Comment: Now it is burried in the Production > Countries/regions tab.